# How to bind datatable having dynamic number of columns to Kendo UI Grid with SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub

I need to bind the Kendo Grid using SignalR with the Datatable that has dynamic number of columns. How can I achieve this. Can I directly pass the DataTable object from Hub to View? My code is as follows:
View:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
<script>
    var TestGridHub = {};
    $(function () {
        TestGridHub = $.connection.TestGridHub;
    })
</script>
<table><tr><td>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("TestGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
      foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in DataTable.Columns)
      {
       columns.Bound(col.ColumnName).Title("Name")
              .ClientTemplate("#=name#");
           }
         })
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .SignalR()
            .PageSize(10)
            .Transport(tr => tr
                .Promise("hubStart")
                .Hub("TestGridHub")
                .Client(c => c.Read("TestGrid_Read"))
                .Server(s => s.Read("TestGrid_Read"))
             )
          .Schema(schema => schema
            .Model(m =>m.Id(p => p.Id))
         ))
        )
    </td></tr></table>
```

Hub:

```
public DataTable TestGrid_Read()
    {
      var queryResult = TestRepository.TestGrid_Read_Dynamic();
      return queryResult;
    }
```

Repository:

```
public DataTable TestGrid_Read_Dynamic()
{
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
        {
          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_TestGrid", connection))
          {
            var dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", GlobalVaribleDeclarations.Id));
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            return dt;
          }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's been more than a few months since you asked this question, but this is something I've been tinkering with and noticed there still wasn't an answer posted. This is what I've done to get it working:

Instead of using `Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)`, use `Html.Kendo().Grid<dynamic>()`

Pass the column definitions in using `ViewData`. I get a `.Clone()` of the DataTable and assign that to `ViewData["columns"]` in the controller, then iterate over that when binding the Grid columns in the view.

The Hub should return the data as a DataTable. If you decide to use server operations then you'll want your Read method to accept a DataSourceRequest parameter and return a DataSourceResult object. You'll need define your own DataSourceResult class so it's Data property is a DataTable.

**Update:** Expanding on how you implement this

So the Grid is built in a mostly similar fashion to any other, but in the Kendo Grid column builder you need to loop through the DataTable's column collection:

```
.Columns(col => 
{
    for(var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if(table.Columns[i].ColumnName == "ID")
        {
            col.Bound(table.Columns[i].ColumnName).Hidden();
        }
        else
        {
            col.Bound(table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
        }
    }
}
```

You can define the Model of the Grid in a similar fashion:

```
.Model(mod => 
{
    for(var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if(table.Columns[i].ColumnName == "ID")
        {
            mod.Id(table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
            mod.Field(table.Columns[i].ColumnName, typeof(table.Columns[i].DataType).Editable(false);
        }
        else
        {
            mod.Field(table.Columns[i].ColumnName, typeof(table.Columns[i].DataType);
        }
    }
}
```

But, even with the model defined to include the data types as above, the Kendo HTML helpers don't know how to choose editors for each column. This can be solved by building a `Stack<string>` of the column names, in the same order they appear in the datatable with the first column at the **top** of the stack, in the Controller and passing it to the view. Then take the Kendo EditorTemplates and modify them to pop a name off the stack and use it for the Editor, like so:

```
//DynamicInteger.cshtml
@model int?

@{
    Stack<string> columnStack = (Stack<string>)ViewData["columns"];
    var name = columnStack.Pop();
}

@(Html.Kendo().IntegerTextBoxFor(m => m).Name(name)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .Min(int.MinValue)
    .Max(int.MaxValue)
)
```

And change the column definition to use the modified EditorTemplates:

```
//...
}
else if (table.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(int))
{
    col.Bound(table.Columns[i].ColumnName).EditorTemplateName("DynamicInteger");
}
```

This will result in the editors being properly assigned to each column, so you get nicely formatted editors, even complex editors like DatePicker or DropDownLists, instead of plain text boxes.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain this solution with the code sample.